# Twitter OAuth in Flex 4 web application

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, twitter-oauth

I want to use Twitter OAuth in my **flex 4 web application** and post tweets, on click of a button.
Please suggest some tutorials or steps to be followed for the same. Also I need to know where should I place the twitter cross domain xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with, to undestand how twitter works: http://dev.twitter.com/

Then you need a Twitter AS3 API, which you can find here:
http://wiki.swfjunkie.com/tweetr
There are some tutorials and examples.